# Creating an MS Excel file which deletes itself when a certain time or date is reached

Tags: excel, vba

Regarding MS Excel, I want to know how to create an Excel file that is deleted from the computer when a certain date or time is reached.

Is it possible? If it is, please tell me how it can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call function `DoSomething` at a certain time in the future or by specifying the time interval by calling `Activate_timer`, but I don't think you can delete workbook direct from VBA. You can try to call in `DoSomething` function some [batch file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file) which closes the book first and then remove it.

```
Sub Activate_timer()
   ' at a certain time in the future
   'Application.OnTime DateSerial(2014,01,01)+TimeSerial(0,0,0), "DoSomething"
   ' or by specifying the time interval
   Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("01:40:00"), "DoSomething"
End Sub

Sub DoSomething()
   'call the batch file
End Sub
```

Comment: sir thanks for your reply... but I don't wanna call this function from VBA. Can this function be written in the file itself??

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you mean, but VBA is integrated in the MS Excel, so when you create new Excel file, you can add an additional functionality into it writing vba code in it (some people call it "write a macros"). So, if you want to write vba function (macros), you should write it direct in your excel file (as you say, "_this function will be written in file itself_"). You can get more information about using VBA in Excel in this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: @simoco yes, you can delete the workbook directly from VBA internal to the same workbook, see below.

Answer (score 7):

If you add this code to the `ThisWorkbook` module, then the workbook will self-destruct if the current date is later than 1 Jan 2014.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
If Now() > #1/1/2014# Then Call SuicideSub
End Sub
```

'

```
Sub SuicideSub()
'courtesy Tom Ogilvy
With ThisWorkbook
.Saved = True
.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
Kill .FullName
.Close False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Any advice to adapt this to Access VBA?

Comment: @110SidedHexagon delete an excel workbook from access? Or an access database?